# Unpack a gzip file that is content-disposition: attachment

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got the url to an api, when I visit the url in browser and pass my login, it will correctly download a zip file, that contains the JSON file with the data I want.

How do I get this JSON by fetching it with Node?

When I call like this

```
const data = await fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
    }
});
```

I correctly receive a **data.body** and **data.headers** but nothing near by the JSON data I am looking for.

Is it even possible to make an API call to a file that is attached?

Comment: so is it loading the file? or are u just getting auth fail, which would also have a body and headers? kinda unclear where u at

Comment: Sorry. The auth is working. The statusText in data.headers is 200. 
Is it possible to fetch an unpack a gzip file that is content-disposition as attachment?

Comment: "Content-Disposition" header is not really relevant here. It only indicates how the browser should handle the file (show/download). It's irrelevant in AJAX requests. If that URL is serving compressed files, then you need a library to read it. Also zip and gzip are not the same thing.

Comment: I receive a readable stream. Can I get this to be the JSON I want?

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
import request from "request";
import zlib from "zlib";
import concat from "concat-stream";

const btoa = (str) => Buffer.from(str).toString("base64");

request(url, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password),
  }})
    .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
    .pipe(
       concat((stringBuffer) => {
         console.log(stringBuffer.toString()) // gives me the json I was looking for
       })
     );
```